# Search based on locale on Sunspot Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'm using the following approach to internationalize models on my app:

```
class GenreLocalization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :genre_id, :name, :locale
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genre_localizations, :dependent => :destroy

  def name(locale = nil)
    locale ||= I18n.locale
    genre_localizations.find_by_locale(locale).name
  end
end
```

If I call `genre.name` it will return the name of the genre on the current locale.

Now I want to index this model with `sunspot solr` based on locales. My ideia is to store a combination of `id`, `localized_name` and `locale` for each row. This way I'm be able to search for genres this way:

```
search = Genre.search do
  keywords params[:search]
  with(:locale, 'en')
end
```

My best approach so far was:

```
searchable do
  Language.supported_locales.each do |locale|
    integer :id, :stored => true
    text    :name, :stored => true, :using => :name(locale)
    string  :locale
  end
end
```

But the line `text    :name, :stored => true, :using => :name(locale)` is (obviously) invalid and I'm stuck trying to find a way to index localized names.

Is there a way to do this? Is this even the correct approach to get localized search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is not a fixed set of genres and you store translations in that table then just create a separate index field for each locale

```
searchable do
  integer :id, :stored => true
  Language.supported_locales.each do |locale|
    text :"name_in_#{locale}", :stored => true do
      name(locale)
    end
  end
end
```

then restrict search on localized name field then

```
search = Genre.search do
  keywords params[:search] do
     fields(:"name_in_#{current_locale}")
  end
end
```

Comment: I18n.backend.flattened_translations returns NoMethodError: undefined method `flattened_translations'. But either way, this is not a fixed set of genres. They are managed by an admin and the admin would set the localized names.

Comment: i changed my answer completely, let me know

Comment: I use the genre_localizations table as a i18n backend for the genre table. A Genre has_many GenreLocalizations (one for each locale) and then I just have to do genre.genre_localizations.find_by_locale(locale).name where locale string is setted by I18n.locale

Comment: Almost there. I can find exact matches by locale now. I'm using a prefix for locale instead of suffix because I'm also indexing a name_splitting field using the following dynamic field in solr schema: <dynamicField name="*_splitting" stored="false" type="text_splitting" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/> but I still can't find partial matches

Comment: The rule for _splitting* was fine. I was committing that field as <field name="en_name_splitting_text"> instead of <field name="en_name_splitting">. Thanks for the help